# When does Web Worker postMessage({}) return to caller

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a recollection of reading that a postMessage request will not return until the onmessage event has been delivered to the recipient.

Having said that, I can't seem to find any reference on the web at the mo and docs such as: -
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html
talk of message "queues" which make me think that messages can be stacked/queued up for processing.

Does someone here have a reference pointer for the prescribed behaviour?

Can a web-page and worker get into a deadlock by simply trying to send messages to each other at the same time?

Comment: There needs to be an onmesage event listener to accept postMessages. I don't think web pages and worker can get into a deadlock because of the way the event loop works.

Comment: I understand how the messaging and onmessage handlers work. What I need to establish is "Can the mainline/boss/web-page that is postMessage(ing) a unit of work to the web worker thread continue once the event is queued in the web worker's queue as opposed to having to wait until the event is DELIVERED to the web worker thread.

Comment: If there is talk of queues, then I think it wouldn't make sense for it to lock until the message is delivered to the worker, as then it wouldn't really be a queue at all.

Answer (score 1):

It returns pretty much immediately. Messages are queued by `postMessage()` and then copied/transferred "behind the scenes" and delivered to workers asynchronously. Same for the other way around. Deadlock should not be possible, unless you halt all processing until you've seen a certain message, of course.